# In node.js express, how can I merge several router at one get method

Tags: node.js, merge, express, router

Suppose I have two router:

```
app.get('blog/show', function () {
  todo();
})

app.get('/admin', function () {
  todo();
})
```

Can I the merge the two router to the same `app.get` method?Mybe something like `app.get('blog/show', '/admin')`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The string in the route match can also be a regex so if you can come up with a regex match to match all the todos, you can do that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bryanmac mentioned, you can do this by specifying the route path as a regex that matches either case:

```
app.get(/blog\/show|\/admin/, function () {
  todo();
});
```

Of course, you could also have both routes use the same named function:

```
function handler() {
  todo();
}
app.get('blog/show', handler);
app.get('/admin', handler);
```